# Lua os.time does not do not work

Tags: lua

I have programed Lua script to a game with function os.clock() and os.time(). Its worked correctly, but after upgrade of this game I have observed fail message : `attempt to call global 'os' (a nil value)... ?` I thought that os.clock() and os.time() are native function of Lua.

Answer (score 2):

From the Lua reference manual:

> Except for the basic and the package libraries, each library provides
>   all its functions as fields of a global table or as methods of its
>   objects.
>
> To have access to these libraries, the C host program should call the
>   luaL_openlibs function, which opens all standard libraries.
>   Alternatively, the host program can open them individually by using ... luaopen_os (for the operating system library)...

As you see adding the standard libraries in a host program is optional. Many applications restrict access to standard libraries. Especially os and io.

As the os librarie has not been added to the scripting environment of your game the global table `os` is `nil`.

So obviously the developers of your game decided that their users should survive without the os functions. Sometimes they just don't want you to do things, sometimes it just doesn't make sense. It is the simplest way to prevent you from interacting with the operatinig system from inside a game.
Usually they also prevent you from loading external code by removing the necessary functions.